# Is connector 50PS-JMDSS-G-1-TF symetrical?

Tags: connector, pinout

I'm looking at a design using connector [50PS-JMDSS-G-1-TF](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eJMD.pdf) and the pin numbers do not match. They are symmetrically switched. So they would match if I could plug the connector the opposite way. Looking at the documentation for 50PS-JMDSS-G-1-TF it looks like it could be plugged both ways.

So my question is whether the 50PS-JMDSS-G-1-TF is symmetrical?

Answer (score 0):

The 50PS-JMDSS-G-1-TF is the side entry connector type, yes? So it would not be usually be possible to slide the card thru card guides and still have the connector end up in the correct location to plug onto the mating connector.

The mating connector does appear to be symmetrical tho.

Comment: There are no "card guides" or other mechanical components preventing the connector to be connected in the opposite way. Except if, and that is my question, the connector itself has some key or similar.